# Displaying something over an inline PDF in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, pdf, bgiframe

I'm writing a little web application that has two things in it :

1. At the top, there is a dropdown menu
   (sooo-called DHTML menus)
2. Below that, there is an IFRAME to
   display the link that you click in
   the menu.

To make the menu appear on top of the iframe in IE, I'm using the jQuery plugin "bgiframe". It works for everything. almost.

From the menu, I mostly call SSRS reports. But, I also call web pages, and in one particular spot I call a PDF file. There is my problem. The PDF renders inline (in the iframe). For that particular control, the bgiframe cannot render my menu on the top of the PDF file.

I have the problem both in IE6, IE7 and IE8. I don't have access to IE9 in the development environment. The problem does not exists in Chrome.

Anyone found a workaround for that?

Thanks

Comment: Ie6 I got one solution for you http://www.ie6countdown.com/ the reset try and use `z-index` in css,  also try an duse `zoom` it changes the layout or rather hasLayout option and in most cases fixes some issues if used right :)

Comment: Yeah I agree for IE6 ;-) But that does not solve the problem right now, since I get the same problem in IE8. I'm using z-index in css, and zoom. I started fresh from html5 boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt that a workaround is possible, because the PDF viewing plugin is a *windowed control* - meaning that IE doesn't have control over that area of screen anymore.

Perhaps the latest IE9 might have something, because it has a severely reworked drawing engine, which uses DirectX. But I don't know.

I suggest restructuring your page somehow so that there is no need for an overlap.

Comment: Windowed controls, like iframe, select, etc. have no problem whatsoever using the bgiframe plugin, which basically shows my menu in a iframe, which is also a windowed element. This is not a windowed control problem.

Comment: @Dominic Goulet - well, I'm not an expert, but I strongly suspect that since IE7 select/iframe/etc aren't windowed controls anymore.